# History API HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, html5-history-api, history-api

Есть 2 элемента, нужно отслеживать их состояние, записывать в url, а после, скопировав ссылку и перейдя по ней должна появится страница с выбранными параметрами из url'a.
Добавил на изменения элементов функции, при которых происходит изменение урла, с этим всё ок, всё меняется и работает, но не понимаю как мне организовать присвоение параметров из урла для этих элементов, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
function change_div_size(){
         history.replaceState({page:1}, "size", '?valsize='+size_va+'&selskin='+sel_skin);
}
sizeSelect.addEventListener("change", change_div_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используемые вами параметры, которые после знака ?, доступны в window.location.search.
Вы можете взять их оттуда строкой, распарсить эту строку и присвоить.